# setting up variable value in php 5.6.23

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am updating my sql query based on the selection made on checkbox

```
        $selected = ($data['selected'] == true) ? 1 : 0;
        echo $data['selected'];
        //prints true when checkbox is checked
        //prints false when unchecked
        echo $sql = "update test_table set selected = " . $selected . " where id = " . $data['product_id'];
```

But in both cases $selected is set to 1 .
When

```
$data['selected'] == false it should save $selected = 0 but it does not.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not sent to the server so you don't have to check for the value, instead you should check if it exists in the POST array.

Comment: @jeroen I am getting $data['selected'] = false on uncheck I just need to store it in database with query and I need $selected = 0

Comment: boolean `true` and `false` will not be passed from a form only strings, maybe `$data['selected'] == 'true'`. Or why not pass `0` and `1` from the form?

Comment: @AbraCadaver post this as an answer it worked => 'true' not true   and I will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are passing `false` as a hidden input and `true` for the checkbox, in which case you will get one or the other; they are passed as strings:

```
$selected = ($data['selected'] == 'true') ? 1 : 0;
```

But I would ask, why not just pass `0` and `1` from the form?

If you are only passing the checkbox as `true`, then:

```
$selected = isset($data['selected']) ? 1 : 0;
```